# Where can I find specifications of my ethernet card?

Tags: ethernet, lan, pci, specifications

As the title says, I've got an ethernet card but not enough specs information.

I have tried looking in Device Manager -> Properties but no dice.  Google searches haven't revealed much.

The card is an

*Atheros AR8121/AR8113/AR8114 PCI-E Ethernet Controller(NDIS6.20)*

...and I'm specifically looking for maximum data transfer rate of the card.

Any links or ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Gigabit ethernet card, so 1000Mb/s but it'd be nice to have a neat way to prove it!

Comment: +1 for the info - yes, it would be nice. How'd you know that it's a Gigabit?

Comment: I googled the first bit of that line, I googled  Atheros AR8121/AR8113/AR8114  . The first link says "Atheros Communications Inc. (R) AR8121/AR8113/AR8114 Gigabit/Fast Ethernet Driver "

Comment: Finding the datasheet for free isn't that likely.. http://old.nabble.com/Re:--Where-to-get-Atheros-AR2317-datasheet-p11629630.html   "Bad news for you Cedric.  Atheros, like Broadcom, Marvel and others.....pretty much won't talk to you unless your building 250K+ EAU.  Atheros has authorized design houses, with contact information on the website.  If you want to engage with them, its $10,000 to do so, and that gives you access to datasheets and not much else.  How do I know? Well...we went down this path about a month or so back, and decided that it wasn't worth doing. "

Comment: but a google of atheros data sheet 8121  comes up with http://www.datasheetarchive.com/Atheros%20AR8121-datasheet.html   but I can't see if they've got it there and if they do it looks like they charge.

Comment: I hope somebody can give a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

In short: it's difficult.

First of all because Qualcomm bought Atheros that bought [Attansic](http://web.archive.org/web/20080706133030/http://www.attansic.com/english/index.html). And with each additional link in the chain it seemed like they cared less and less about Ethernet (so much that latest hardware is better off [downgraded](https://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/guide-turn-your-killer-e2200-nic-into-qualcomm-atheros-ar8161.198899/)).

Second, there's an incredible amount of confusion between the [transceivers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHY_(chip)#Ethernet_physical_transceiver) ([AR80xx](http://web.archive.org/web/20070729000553/http://www.atheros.com/news/AR8021.htm)) and actual complete network controllers ([AR81xx](http://web.archive.org/web/20071203004937/http://www.atheros.com/news/AR8316_AR8121.htm)).

Now, the close temporal proximity of 8021 and 8121 presentations makes me suppose the former is inside the latter. And [according](http://datasheet.datasheetarchive.com/originals/library/Datasheets-SW6/DSASW00118741.pdf) [to](http://web.archive.org/web/20110208134108/http://www.atheros.com/technology/technology.php?nav1=48&product=92) [documents](http://www.netcheif.com/Reviews/TPL-401E/PDF/product_92_file1.pdf) the first is definitely Gigabit (so I would suppose the NIC)

But then, for as much the driver and PID might be the [same](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/NET_VENDOR_ATHEROS.html), let's remember we are still talking about 3 separate chips. And [AR8113](https://web.archive.org/web/20170109120841/http://onns.ru/datasheet/dda3884419f2835f54b6bff225195a78.pdf) datasheet confirms that's just 10/100.
As for AR8114.. I could only find [sparse](https://usermanual.wiki/Document/compalla4861pr1schematics.502625948/view#page=25) and [discordant](http://www.clubedohardware.com.br/forums/topic/556574-review-acer-6920g-6920-6864-t55503gb169500gstuba-booster/) info.

So, it all depends.

Answer (score 1):

According to this page, it's 10/100mbps card.
http://www.atheros.cz/atheros-network-drivers.php

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely NOT ALWAYS a gigabit interface...!

I own an Asus Eee-PC 901 with UMTS module which has this ethernet interface. A long time I thought to have a gigabit ethernet in it - but yesterday I found out it is not (against a Pogoplug E02, which allows a gigabit connection with same cable and another PC with same OS), my AR81xx has a maximum link speed of 100 MBit/s.